# How does one share a link to a hot question?

Tags: support, badges, hyperlinks

Message: "share a link to this hot question to earn the publicist badge".

How does one do this?

Comment: Related: [What is the mechanism for earning the 'Publicist' badge?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1787)

Comment: FYI (for those seeing that a 13 year old question is closed as a duplicate of a 12 year old question:  the linked "duplicate" contains a comment pointing towards the main meta site.  Also, the answer here has become somewhat obsoleted by changes in the UI over time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can refer to the question [*new badges - how to “share” a link?*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/63684/145210) on meta.SO. Basically:

- Right click on the "link" link and copy the URL

[image]

- or use those Facebook/Twitter icons

[image]