# What is the mechanism for earning the 'Publicist' badge?

Tags: discussion, support, badges, hyperlinks

Every so often, I get a popup in a question that says 'earn the publicist badge by creating a link to ...'.

The badge page explains "Publicist" means "Shared a link to a question that was visited by 1000 unique IP addresses in 5 days. "

Is the expectation that these are links -outside- of math.stackexchange?

If so, I don't see how stackexchange could possibly count those kinds of accesses.

If not, 1000 in unlimited days is pretty difficult, given that very few math.stackexchange questions get above 1000 views even over a long time.

So, how is that implemented?

Publicist badge - how is it earned?

Comment: This question has been asked and answered on meta.SO: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68502/how-do-i-earn-the-publicist-badge

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to the link Rahul provided

[How do I earn the publicist badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68502/how-do-i-earn-the-publicist-badge)

There is a blog entry explaining it as well

https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/09/announcer-booster-and-publicist-badges

IPs must come from outside the SE network to be counted.

Comment: Excellent...thanks (and to Rahul). meta-meta question (given the close vote of 1) - I'm guessing I should have known to go to meta.stackoverflow, but that's not obvious since that presumably is the meta -just- for the programming site, stackoverflow, not -all- of the sites.

Comment: @Mitch: It is _not_ the meta just for the programming site but the mother of all metas.